# How to parse a string with multiple characters to split on-Bash Scripting

Tags: bash

I have a text file with the following contents:

> folder4/file2folder4.txt >> folder2/folder2_1/file1folder2.txt

I have a script that parses each lines as follows

```
while IFS=" >> " read -r src dest
do 

    if [ "$src" != "" ]; then
        SOURCEFILES+=("$src")
    fi
    if [ "$dest" != "" ]; then  
        DESTINATIONFILES+=("$dest")
    fi  
done < $TransferDescriptor
```

It parses as follows:

> SOURCEFILE="folder4/file2folder4.txt"
>
> DESTINATION="> folder2/folder2_1/file1folder2.txt"

But what I want

> SOURCEFILE="folder4/file2folder4.txt"
>
> DESTINATION="folder2/folder2_1/file1folder2.txt"

Any help. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`IFS` is not a single, multicharcter delimiter; instead, it is a collection of single-character delimiters. You can use a regular expression to break apart two fields separated by an arbitrary delimiter.

```
regex='(.*) >> (.*)'
while IFS= read -r line dest
do 
    [[ $line =~ $regex ]] || continue
    src=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    dest=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}

    if [[ -n $src ]]; then
        SOURCEFILES+=("$src")
    fi
    if [[ -n $dest ]]; then  
        DESTINATIONFILES+=("$dest")
    fi  
done < "$TransferDescriptor"
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot multiple character string in `IFS`. It only supports single characters to be used as input field separator.

You can make use of BASH regular expressions here like this:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
   if [[ $line =~ $re ]] ; then
      srcfile="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
      dest="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
   fi
done < file
```

Check our variable:

```
declare -p srcfile dest
declare -- srcfile="folder4/file2folder4.txt"
declare -- dest="folder2/folder2_1/file1folder2.txt"
```