# How to read yaml file into bash associative array?

Tags: bash, yaml, associative-array

I want to read into bash associative array the content of one yaml file, which is a simple key value mapping.

Example `map.yaml`

```
---

a: "2"
b: "3"
api_key: "somekey:thatcancontainany@chara$$ter"
```

the key can contain any characters excluding space  
the value can contain any characters without limitations $!:=@etc

What will always be constant is the separator between key and value is `:`

the script `proceses.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A map
# how to read here into map variable, from map.yml file
#map=populatesomehowfrommap.yaml

for key in "${!map[@]}"
do
  echo "key  : $key"
  echo "value: ${map[$key]}"
done
```

I tried to play around with [yq tool](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), similar to json tool jq but did not have success yet.

Comment: Since you didn't show how you used `yq` and how you filled `map`, we can't say what you did wrong.

Comment: I did not add that because don't want to limit solutions to only using yq. Feel free comment any solution with or without yq that achieves the goal. Meanwhile I will post my faulty yq solution update question

Comment: Is that your actual yaml? Nested items makes this a lot harder.

Comment: Yes that is my actual yaml, it is and will be flat only key => value map where value is always a string

Comment: For reading a formatted file, you need to write a parser. For a **general** YAML file, you either have to re-invent the wheel and develop your own parser, or use an existing one. `yq` is just an example; you can use a different one. Things may be simpler, if you can ensure that your YAML input does not contain any possible valid YAML code, but is restricted to a certain YAML subset. In this case you need to define, how the data may look like (given a small example is, for sure, **not** a definition).

Comment: @user1934428 that is the definition of my yaml. I always expect key value map, both are string. Nothing is nested

Comment: Is every key/value association always on a single line? Can the values have double-quotes or colons embedded? You need to be more specific what can or cann not be between the delimiting quotes....

Comment: yes it is a valid yaml file, every definition is in a new line and always surrounded by `"` like in the provided example map.yml

Comment: `bash` doesn't have nested arrays, so there's little reason to support decoding arbitrary YAML. Use a different language.

Comment: sorry! yes it is a typo, updating now and closing "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following limitations:

- simple YAML `key: "value"` in single lines
- keys can**not** contain `:`
- values are always wrapped in `"`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A map
regex='^([^:]+):[[:space:]]+"(.*)"[[:space:]]*$'

while IFS='' read -r line
do
    if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]
    then
        printf -v map["${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"] '%b' "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    else
        echo "skipping: $line" 1>&2
    fi
done < map.yaml
```

---

###### Update

Here's a robust solution using `yq`, which would be simpler if the builtin `@tsv` filter implemented the lossless TSV escaping rules instead of the CSV ones.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A map

while IFS=$'\t' read key value
do
    printf -v map["$key"] '%b' "$value"
done < <(
    yq e '
        to_entries | .[] |
        [
            (.key   | sub("\\","\\") | sub("\n","\n") | sub("\r","\r") | sub("\t","\t")),
            (.value | sub("\\","\\") | sub("\n","\n") | sub("\r","\r") | sub("\t","\t"))
        ] |
        join("  ")
    ' map.yaml
)
```

<sup>**note:** the `join` needs a literal <kbd>Tab</kbd></sup>

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and got error like `process.sh: line 18: printf: `map[ssm_api_key]': not a valid identifier
` Line 18 in my modified script is `printf -v map["${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"] '%b' "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"` and my map.yml has one extra key `ssm_api_key: "somesecretkey:2323"`

Comment: it feels like you're not using bash-4+; are you running it on macOS or with a `sh` shebang?

Comment: first line of bash is `#!/usr/bin/env bash`  yes bash version seems not to be 4 `bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin21)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Comment: @KristiJorgji: as user1934428 has pointed out in the comments, you need to provide more details on your actual data; you were asked if the data can contain embedded colons but you never responded, nor does your sample data demonstrate embedded colons but *now* ... you're telling Fravadona the data contains embedded colons; please update the question with a more respresentative set of data along with details on what characters may (not) exist in the data

Comment: @markp-fuso I updated my question now with extra key value pair and mentioning that can contain any character

Comment: bash-3 doesn't have associative arrays, you can't load your data with it

Comment: I used `brew upgrade bash` and now got version 5. I runned again and worked correctly. This solution works. Can I assume that value can have any value ? The limitation of not containing `:` is only for the key right ?\

Comment: There is no constraint that associative array keys can't contain `:`

Answer (score 1):

One way, is by letting [yq](/questions/tagged/yq) output each key/value pair on a single line, in the following syntax:

```
key@value
```

Then we can use [bash's IFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184863/what-is-the-meaning-of-ifs-n-in-bash-scripting) to split those values.
<sub>The `@` is just an example and can be replaced with any single char</sub>

---

This works, but **please note the following limitations**:

- It does not expect nested values, only a flat list`
- The field seperator (`@` in the example) does not exist in the YAML key/value's

---

```sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -A arr
while IFS="@" read -r key value
do
    arr[$key]="$value"
done < <(yq e 'to_entries | .[] | (.key + "@" + .value)' input.yaml)

for key in "${!arr[@]}"
do
    echo "key  : $key"
    echo "value: ${arr[$key]}"
done
```

```
$ cat input.yaml
---
a: "bar"
b: "foo"

$
$
$ ./script.sh
key  : a
value: bar
key  : b
value: foo
$
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I have `=` in the value of the keys. Can be base64 and other values that contain =

Comment: You can use another separator, as long as it's not in the key/value.

Comment: can IFS be more then one character long? I tried and only uses first char. My concern is that value can have any possible string (also credentials keys base64 etc) so might end up in bugs due to ifs of value `@` or something else being present in value as well...

Comment: You can make the IFS based on a regex. Please see [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635429/how-to-parse-a-string-with-multiple-characters-to-split-on-bash-scripting). Not sure if that will fix your problem tho since you're not sure what chars might be there.

Comment: I am getting on bash mac m1, `bash: declare: -A: invalid option` ` echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
`

Answer (score 0):

I used @Fravadona s answer so will mark it as answer

After some modification to my use case, what worked for me looks like:

```
DEFS_PATH="definitions"

declare -A ssmMap
for file in ${DEFS_PATH}/*
do
    filename=$(basename -- "$file")
    projectName="${filename%.*}"

    regex='^([^:]+):[[:space:]]*"(.*)"[[:space:]]*$'
    while IFS='' read -r line
    do
        if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]
        then
            value="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
            value=${value//"{{ ssm_env }}"/$INFRA_ENV}
            value=${value//"{{ ssm_reg }}"/$SSM_REGION}
            value=${value//"{{ projectName }}"/$projectName}
            printf -v ssmMap["${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"] '%b' "$value"
        else
            echo "skipping: $line" 1>&2
        fi
    done < "$file"
done
```

Basically in real use case I have one folder where yaml definitions are located. I iterate over all of them to form the associative array ssmMap